# Change background color of cell based on time passed after edit in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I think this would be a neat feature that could be applied to many spreadsheets in Google Doc, I just don't know how to do it.

The general idea would to highlight cells that have been recently edited and have them change back to a neutral background color (or no color) after a set time.

To me (and probably others) this would be extremely useful to quickly view a spreadsheet and see what has been recently changed.

Ideally I would make it so that a cell edited within the past 2 hours would be light green, 12 hours be  light yellow, and 48 hours be light red, and anything after that would reset the background color.

Any ideas to make this happen? Thanks!

Comment: You could create a timestamp of when the cells were edited and collect those in a separate sheet. Then 'onOpen' you would check the current time against the edited timestamp, and if the passed time is over a certain amount, change the cells back. Bottom line - make the trigger 'onOpen'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use conditional format.

You can find it at the menu: **format > conditional format**

On the conditional format you can use a DATE format or a CUSTOM FORMULA.

---

Sample:

- Let suppose you have in a cell (G5) a specific date.
- And in another cell (H3) you have the current day.
- With CUSTOM FORMULA you can write a code something like `=days(H3,G5)<7`

> The sample code say: if the current date on cell H3 and the date on cell G5 are different by 7 days?

- If the condition is TRUE then the CUSTOM FORMAT will by apply to the cell.

  - The only downside of this method is if you have multiples cell you need to add the formula one by one.

However, in the Conditional format you can also use the **Color scale**.

Hope this can help you